# mod-rewrite: Rewrite rule constantly adds .php to the end of some URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my web server, I have a few rewrite rules added to my .htaccess file located in the document root (in my case, `/var/www/main/public_html/.htaccess`). The purpose of these rewrite rules are to remove the need for .php and .html file extensions in the URL.

Here's the problem: It works perfectly for *most* URLs. However, when attempting to access subdirectories that are actually files, the rewrite rule keeps adding .php to the end until the server gives up and throws a `500` error.

To better explain the issue... Lets say my file struture looked like this:
`/index.php`
`/file.php`
`/folder/index.php`
`/folder/file.php`

These URLs display pages correctly:
`example.com`
`example.com/index`
`example.com/file`
`example.com/folder`
`example.com/folder/index`
`example.com/folder/file`

This strange looping happens however on a URL like this:
`example.com/index/file`
`example.com/file/index`
In the case of `/index/file`, the logs show:
`[core:debug] [pid 253721] core.c(3849): [client #####] AH00121: r->uri = /index/file.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php`
Expected result is that a URL such as `example.com/index/file` would result in a `404` error

And everything else displays a 404 as expected:
`example.com/badfile`
`example.com/folder/badfile`
`example.com/badfolder/file`

I'm not super experienced with rewrite rules and don't really know what I'm doing :D
I'm almost certain I've made a stupid mistake somewhere.
Any help would be appreciated!

The server is self-hosted running on Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache2.

This is what my .htaccess file contains:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# External Redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

# Internal Redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
```

Comment: Have a try using the `[END]` flag instead of the `[L]` flag in your internal redirections. Keep in mind that the `[L]` flag only terminates rewriting _for this round_ , so the rewriting process is actually restarted and may further rewrite the current request. Which most likely is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # Internal Redirect
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
> RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
> ```

The *problem* is your "internal redirect/rewrite". The *condition* (eg. `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html`) is not necessarily testing the same thing that you are ultimately rewriting to in the *substitution* string (eg. `%{REQUEST_URI}.html`) which results in an endless rewrite loop under certain scenarios. (Yes, using the `END` flag - as mentioned in comments - would prevent the rewrite loop, however, this does not address the underlying issue and would still result in an incorrect rewrite and the "wrong URL" being logged as a 404.)

When requesting a URL of the form `example.com/index/file` (where `index` also maps to a `.php` *or* `.html` file and is not a physical directory) then the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable is of the form `/path/to/index` (note the missing `/file`), but `REQUEST_URI` is `/index/file` (the requested URL). So, the *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) is successful (since `/path/to/index.php` exists), but the request is incorrectly rewritten to `/index/file.php` - which does not exist. The rewrite engine then starts over and the same issue occurs. (The `END` flag causes the rewrite engine to stop after the first "incorrect" rewrite.)

These rules should be written like this instead:

```
# Internal Redirect
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

The preceding *condition* is now testing the same file-path that we are ultimately rewriting to in the *substitution* string.

For further reading/explanation/examples, see [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following question on ServerFault (StackOverflow's sister site on server management):

- https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was likely I had made a stupid mistake.

Comment: @EthanBlaisAlarms You're welcome. It wasn't a "stupid" mistake. The behaviour of `REQUEST_FILENAME` isn't necessarily intuitive at first, and the rule would work for all "normal" requests. In fact, this is a surprisingly common error (that has unfortunately propagated around the internet). FWIW I've noticed that ChatGPT 3.5 also makes the same mistake(s).